# Unity, Rigidbody Character keeps falling over

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have a problem with trying to keep my character from rolling over, yet allow it to pitch and yaw. The suggestions I have seen have been to lock different axis, but no matter if I lock the x, y, or z axis I always run into a situation where the character can fall over. The best I can get is to lock both the y and z axis. This allows the character to change pitch to conform to the terrain. But, again, if I turn left or right while going up or down a hill and I can roll the character over.

Here is my current code for movement (in case it helps). I have no other code and my rigid body is all defaults. I have a mesh collier for the character set to convex but defaults otherwise.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?
Here's a live demo of y and z axis being locked. Just waltz up the hill and hang a left or right and you'll fall over. (ASWD controls)

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27946381/Builds/builds.html

Thanks so much!

```
var speed = 3.0;
var rotateSpeed = 3.0;

function FixedUpdate() {

    var hAxis = 0;
    var vAxis = 0;

    if( Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 ) { hAxis = 1.0; } else if( Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 ) { hAxis = -1.0; } else { hAxis = 0.0; }
        if( Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 ) { vAxis = 1.0; } else if( Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0 ) { vAxis = -1.0; } else { vAxis = 0.0; }

    var rigidBody: Rigidbody = GetComponent(Rigidbody);

    // Rotate around y axis
    // transform.Rotate(0, hAxis * rotateSpeed, 0);
    var deltaRotation : Quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(0, hAxis * rotateSpeed, 0);
    rigidbody.MoveRotation(rigidbody.rotation * deltaRotation);

    // Move forward / backward
    var forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    var currSpeed = speed * vAxis;

    rigidBody.MovePosition( rigidBody.position + (forward * currSpeed) );

    var animatorController: Animator = GetComponent(Animator);
    animatorController.SetFloat("Speed", currSpeed);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

well maybe you should check your rigidbody properties called gravity scale.. set it to 0 and you will never fall

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in these MovePosition and MoveRotation. Take a look into scripting reference - these methods basically ignores collision until body is teleported at the specified pose. I.e. you may place the body into some kind of irresolvable situation, when physics engice unable to find appropriate forces to push the body away from another collider, and therefore the body will fall through. In this case it is better to use AddForce and AddTorque.

Also, you can use **CharacterController** instead of **RigidBody**. Though it cannot be rotated at all, there are fine methods for kinematic motion with precise collision detection. And you can attach another body to the character controller and rotate it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Changing code will change nothing.

1. Try changing the hitbox of the player to a big cube
2. (Better) Try to look into the rigidbody properties, as far as I remember I had the same problem and fixed it that way, it might help